# Why does my program get an error when calling getWritableDatabase() on a SQLite DatabaseHelper class?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am trying to create a database in Android. Here is the code that causes the error:

```
DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Here is my DatabaseHelper class:

```
package com.example.livelab;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public static final String TABLE_CALLS = "calls";
  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
  public static final String COLUMN_CALL_NUMBER = "number";
  public static final String COLUMN_CALL_DATE = "date";
  public static final String COLUMN_CALL_DURATION = "duration";

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LiveLab.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  // SQL statement for creating our CALLS table.
  private static final String CALLS_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_CALLS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
      + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_CALL_NUMBER
      + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_CALL_DATE
      + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_CALL_DURATION
      + " text not null);";

   public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(CALLS_CREATE);
   }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(),
        "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
             + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CALLS);
    onCreate(db);
  }

}
```

For some reason, calling helper.getWritableDatabase() causes a new window to pop up that says:

ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread$CreateServiceData)
Source not found.

What is the cause of this?

By the way, this is all in a Service and not in an Activity.

Comment: Please post all of your LogCat errors.

Comment: My only LogCat error is: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x0000001a7 (code=0)

Comment: I don't think you should have more than one column declared as a primary key.  Can't believe that would cause a popup though.

Comment: Oh, and post more of your logcat.  Need some context

Comment: That actually solved my problem! Thanks! (I am new to SQL let alone Android)